# modifying a sorted result with xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, ibm-datapower

In my request xml there is a tag  whose value when sent to a web service returns a list of names in response. The initial requirement was to sort the names in response alphabetically which i implemented using xsl:sort function. Now the requirement has changed a bit and I am not able to figure out the code for it. pls see below the Request, Sorted Response and the expected Response.

```
Request:    <BillerName>Dir</BillerName>

Sorted Response:    <Name>AT Direct</Name>
                    <Name>Direct AV</Name>
                    <Name>Direct SV</Name>
                   <Name>The Direct AV</Name>

Expected Response: <Name>Direct AV</Name>
                   <Name>Direct SV</Name>
                   <Name>AT Direct</Name>
                   <Name>The Direct AV</Name>
```

So Bascially, the Names starting with the value of the BillerName tag in te request sold come first and ten the rest of te sorted names.

How can I implement this?

Answer (score 2):

Use two sort keys, a major and a minor:

```
<xsl:for-each select="Name">
  <xsl:sort select="not(starts-with(., $BillerName))"/>
  <xsl:sort select="."/>
  ...
</xsl:for-each>
```

This relies on knowing that false sorts before true.

Comment: Hi Michael,

Thanks for your help, It is working fine. Just want to know what would happen if i use just the first sort key which uses starts-with function and not the second one.

Comment: XSLT states that the sort is stable, which means that if two items have the same values for the sort key(s), they are output in their original order (the order they appeared in the input)

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
<xsl:variable name="BillerName" select="BillerName"/>

<xsl:for-each select="Name[starts-with(., $BillerName)]">
    <xsl:sort/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:for-each>

<xsl:for-each select="Name[not(starts-with(., $BillerName))]">
    <xsl:sort/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:for-each>
```